# Is it possible to solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

We have $f(x,n)$, $g(n)$ and

$$8(n+1)^{3}(n+2)(f(x,n)-g(n))^2f_{x}(x,n+1)=2(n+1)(2f_{x}(x,n)f_{xx}(x,n)(f(x,n)-g(n))-(f_{x}(x,n)^3))$$

Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: It depends on what $n$ is. Is it an integer parameter? Is this a recursive formula?

Comment: Well assume n is not an integer parameter. It's a parameter like x.

Comment: In that case, this is a delay equation in $n$, and the solution comes in chunks with width $1$. You need an initial condition on $n\in [0,1)$ (which also must satisfy the differential part in $x$), and then you build the solution recursively. Unless $f_x(x,n+1)$ is a mistake :)